# Can I use ctypes to call back C function from python embedded in C?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes, python-extensions

I have a C program with embedded python code. I have compiled python 2.7.2 from source and linked my program against libpython2.7.a.

Now in my python code I wish to call back functions from other C libraries linked into my C program. I can write a python extension (see Extending Embedded Python in [this document](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html)). However, **ctypes** would make this a lot easier and would allow me to use some existing code unchaged.

**ctypes** is geared towards loading shared libraries and I was wondering if there was a way to 'point' it back to my static program code.

*I cannot compile the relevant code into a shared library because my target is iOS and AFAIK shared libraries are forbidden by Apple.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Python code, you can create ctypes wrappers for static functions like this:

```
restype = ctypes.c_int
argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_double]        # or whatever
functype = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
wrapper = functype(address_of_static_function_as_an_int)
```

You can of course call this (or similar) code from your C code.

Comment: For some reason this crashes my (static) libffi in _ctypes.

Comment: @Avner: Honestly, I did not actually *try* the above code, so I can't help you with that crash.

Comment: The code looks right (this is why I accepted your answer). I suspect the problem is with the porting of libffi to iOS and the way I compiled libpython.a (with static modules, static _ctypes and static libffi). But since I did not yet solve this crash, this remains a suspicion for now.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a ctypes value (e.g. `ctypes.c_void_p`) encapsulating your function pointer and pass it into your Python code.